# Struggling to understand the new BBM update

Tags: iphone

I have an old iPhone that had the old version of BBM (Blackberry Messenger) installed. If I were to charge it and load the app (now that it is off of the AppStore and shut down) will I still be able to access my old chats or see old photos?

Comment: What is BBM and why don't you just try?

Comment: Oh bbm was a messanger service that was available on Android and Apple from around 2013. The only issue is my old iPhone requires the old side chargers which I don’t have and would need to order. So I am just hoping someone will have an answer

Answer (score 1):

> ...will I still be able to access my old chats or see old photos?

**No, they’re gone**.

BBM messenger was shutdown May 31st, 2019 and users had until the following Friday to download messages, photos, videos, and files.

Source:  [C|Net, BlackBerry Messenger shuts down: What you need to know](https://www.cnet.com/news/blackberry-messenger-shuts-down-today-what-you-need-to-know/)

The “new” BBM app is their enterprise version and it’s completely different and is referred to in the article as a “replacement.”  Nothing was migrated from consumer to enterprise.